# Tableview keeps going back to top? After leaving to "detailed" vc?

Tags: swift

How can I prevent the view controller from starting from the top of the feed when a user leaves and goes back?

Basically, I have the main VC and a detailed VC.  When the user selects a cell, it should jump to the detailed VC.  If she/he goes back, it should leave her back to where she/he was.

I get that my code is calling "reload Data" every time the VC loads, but what other options do I have then if I don't call that method?

Here's an image of my main storyboard if it helps.  Main VC(left) is the feed tableView where the user can tap on the cell.  When he/she taps on the cell, it "segues" to the comment table VC (right).  When he/she is done commenting she/he can go back to the main VC and continuing going down the feed. (ideally, except it keeps loading from the newest post, rather than segueing the user back to where she/he was down in the feed)

[image]

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        
        let post: PostModel

        
        post = postList[indexPath.row]
        
        func set(post: PostModel) {
            ImageService.downloadImage(withURL: post.author.patthToImage) { image in
                cell.profileImage.image = image
            }
        }
        set(post: postList[indexPath.row])
        cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // line wrap
        cell.descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = post.message

        cell.authorLabel.text = post.author.username

        cell.timeLabel.text = post.createdAt.calendarTimeSinceNow()
        
        //takes care of post image hidding and showing
        if self.postList[indexPath.row].pathToImage != "" {
            cell.postImage.isHidden = false
            cell.postImage?.downloadImage(from: self.postList[indexPath.row].pathToImage)
        
        } else {
            cell.postImage.isHidden = true

        }
        
        if cell.postImage.isHidden == true {
            cell.postImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
            
        }

        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let post: PostModel
        
        post = postList[indexPath.row]
        myIndex = indexPath.row
        myPost = post.postID!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        print(myIndex)
        print(post.postID)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        beginBatchFetch()
        
    }

    func beginBatchFetch() {
        fetchingMore = true

        fetchPosts { newPosts in
            self.postList.append(contentsOf: newPosts)

            self.endReached = newPosts.count == 0
            self.fetchingMore = false
            self.tableViewPost.reloadData()
 
        }

    }
    func fetchPosts(completion: @escaping(_ postList:[PostModel])->()) {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        var queryRef:DatabaseQuery
        let lastPost = self.postList.last
        
        if lastPost != nil {
            let lastTimestamp = lastPost!.createdAt.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
            queryRef = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: lastTimestamp).queryLimited(toLast:20)
        } else {
            queryRef = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast:20)
        }
        
        queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            var tempPosts = [PostModel]()


            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                    let author = dict["author"] as? [String:Any],
                    let uid = author["uid"] as? String,
                    let username = author["username"] as? String,
                    let fullname = author["fullname"] as? String,
                    let patthToImage = author["patthToImage"] as? String,
                    let url = URL(string:patthToImage),

                    let pathToImage = dict["pathToImage"] as? String,
                    let likes = dict["likes"] as? Int,
                    let postID = dict["postID"] as? String,
                    let message = dict["message"] as? String,
                    let genre = dict["genre"] as? String,
                    let timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double {


                    let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: uid, fullname: fullname, username: username, patthToImage: url)
                    let post = PostModel(genre: genre, likes: likes, message: message, pathToImage: pathToImage, postID: postID, userID: pathToImage, timestamp: timestamp, id: childSnapshot.key, author: userProfile)
                    tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
                }
            }

            //first two
            self.postList = tempPosts
            self.tableViewPost.reloadData()
//            return completion(tempPosts)
        })
```

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller or presenting modally when showing the detailed VC? So long as the main VC remains in memory, I don't know why it would reload at the top.

Comment: "jump to the detailed VC" What does "jump to" mean? How are you getting to the detailed VC?

Comment: Also, can you provide some code as to how you're implementing the table view (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`) and how you're presenting the detailed VC?

Comment: And also please show any `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` implementations in the main VC.

Comment: @David edit.  Actually I'm not sure how to answer.  I have the two screens connected in the main story board.  And then I use a func called didSelectRow to initiate the segue when the user taps on a cell in the main VC....

Comment: @matt By jump, I mean segueing to the detailed VC.  I have it connected through the main story board, and then I have a func called didSelectRow to imitate the segue

Comment: @ezera.olsen You're actually likely presenting modally if you are using the `performSegue` method.

Comment: But what kind of segue is it? And why do you have a segue _and_ didSelect? That sounds like a mistake. You could end up segueing twice at the same time.

Comment: @DavidChopin is that the incorrect method?

Comment: Also how do you get back from the detail vc to the table? I hope you are not using another segue.

Comment: @ezera.olsen not necessarily. Neither segueing nor pushing via a navigation controller should cause your table view to scroll to the top. Can you show us the code fro the `fetchPosts` method?

Comment: @matt I imagine that may be the issue.

Comment: @matt It's a "show" segue.  I added the didSelectRow because it was a tableview that the user selects taps from.  The best example would be like twitter feed.  If the user taps on the cell it should present the detailed view, yes. I added a "back" button to segue back

Comment: @DavidChopin yes, added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as Matt pointed out, is that you are segueing to the detailVC and then segueing back to the original VC. This is creating a new instance of the original VC.

What you should do, in your VC with the table view, is instantiate and present the destination view controller when a cell is selected. So you should replace `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)` with something like:

```swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
var destinationVC = (storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationVC") as! DestinationViewController)
present(destinationVC!, animated: ture, completion: nil)
```

**NOTE:** View Controller storyboard identifiers can be set in the interface builder. So, if you are wanting to use this line: `var destinationVC = (storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationVC") as! DestinationViewController)`, you will first have to set the Storyboard ID in the interface builder:

[image]

Now, within your destination view controller, instead of segueing when your done button is pressed, you want to use the `dismiss` method to dismiss the presented view controller.

```swift
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now, the original VC with the table view stays in memory while the destination VC is presented over it. When the user presses the "back" button, it will dismiss the destination VC and the original VC should reappear as you left it.

Answer (score 0):

"I added a "back" button to segue back" That's the problem. The way to go back is to call `dismiss` — not use a second segue (unless it is a special "unwind" segue, but you don't know how to do that).