# Gif disappears in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimage, gif

I'm using the answer of this question: [How to load GIF image in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/how-to-load-gif-image-in-swift/27922518) and I'm adding the gif into UITableViewCell. When you open the table, it works and it is animating, but when I go to another UIViewController and return to the UITableViewController the gif is not there. It appears only when you .touchUpOutside the UITableViewCell. How to fix that issue ?

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var theImageView: UIImageView!{
        didSet{
            let loadingGif = UIImage.gifImageWithName("loading")
            theImageView.image = loadingGif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you "going to another UIViewController"? Are you using segues or a navigation controller or what? You may be creating a second instance of the UIViewController that has the table view in it. See if this post about segueing to a view controller and then segueing back is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260379/tableview-keeps-going-back-to-top-after-leaving-to-detailed-vc/58260705#58260705

Comment: Could you put some code?

Comment: With BarButtonItem or UITableViewCell click doesn't matter. When the UITableViewController disappear the gif also disappear. Use the code above and and add gif to UITableViewCell to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to show all stages of showing animated gif on the UITableViewCell

1) This is my GifTableViewController that contains a UITableView

```
import UIKit

class GifTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var gifs = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadGifs()
    }

    func loadGifs() {
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/XIqCQx02E1U9W/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/11JTxkrmq4bGE0/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/eoxomXXVL2S0E/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/c5wbvuaVVLWzC/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/l9Jhzwdi09Ve0/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/8h1Zhv62CVXEc/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/FgiHOQyKUJmwg/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/h2MLtoOjxtkGY/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/ClKnUxoh4SP16/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/S6fA9ppFTwFhK/giphy.gif")
        gifs.append("https://media.giphy.com/media/EGiBhTZMXedIA/giphy.gif")
    }

}


extension GifTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gifs.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GifTableCell", for: indexPath) as! GifTableCell
        cell.load(with: gifs[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }

}
```

2) This is my GifTableCell that contains a UIImageView which will represent gif on

```
import UIKit

class GifTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var gifImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func load(with urlString: String) {
        gifImageView.image = nil
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString as String) else {
                return
            }
            guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.gifImageView.image = UIImage.gif(data: data)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

3) Notice that `UIImage.gif(data: data)` statement. The gif function is an UIImage extension from the SwiftGifOrigin library

See source: https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif

You can add only `UIImage+Gif.swift` file in order to use by simply, or include SwiftGifOrigin library into your project.

**Edits for question update;**

The above example shows that gifs are loaded from url. Your case is actually much simpler, your cell should be like this.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var theImageView: UIImageView!

    func loadGif() {
        theImageView.image = nil
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            let loadingGif = UIImage.gifImageWithName("loading")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.theImageView.image = loadingGif
            }
        }
    }

}
```